# Using Media Query - which tags do I target?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, media

within my HTML I have used CSS to specify Width on several of my tags. When setting CSS for a Media Query do I need to list every single tag that has a specific width? If so, how? Keep it in ratio to what it is for full screen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Jenifer Troska</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/icon.ico"/>



</head>

<body>
<div id="mainWrap">
<div id="mainPanel">
 <div id="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><div class="blank"></div></li>
   <li><a href="about.html"><span>About&nbsp;Me</span></a></li>
   <li><div class="blank"></div></li>
   <li><a href="family.html"><span>Family</span></a></li>
   <li><div class="blank"></div></li>
   <li><a href="projects.html"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
   <li></li>
   <li><div class="blank"></div></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
  <div id="logoWrap"><h1>Jenifer Troska</h1>
  </div>
 <div id="webdesign"> -strong, healthy web design </div>
 <div id="quots"><p>&quot;The purpose of life is to live it, to taste experience to the utmost, to reach out eagerly and without fear for newer and richer experience.&quot; 
</p>
   <p>― Eleanor Roosevelt</p>
 </div>
 <div id="leftPanel">
  <div class="about">
   <h2>Welcome! You can call me Jen.</h2>
   <h3>Glad you found me</h3>
   <p><span>This is my personal website! Second website I've created! </span><br />
      Within my website you will find photos and information about me, my family and information about my new found interest into web design! Keep in mind I'm a beginner! I am having a blast playing around with web design but do not {DO NOT} consider myself a professional. See something corny? See something you would change? I take and appreciate constructive criticism. See &quot;contact &quot; to send these thoughts my way.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="services">
   <h2>Spectrum of Services</h2>
   <div class="pic"></div>
   <p>I run a registered in-home childcare and design websites on the side.</p>
   <h3>Services</h3>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Small Business &amp; Personal Web Design (coming soon!)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="bottom">In-Home Childcare (coming soon)</a></li>
   </ul>
   <p><span>Use these links to learn about my work and see what services I have to offer.</span> </p>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial">
   <h2>Testimonial</h2>
   <p> <span>I don't have any yet.</span></p>
   <h3><span>by</span> who wants to be the first?</h3>
    <p><span>I don't have any yet.</span></p>
   <h3><span>by</span> who wants to be second?</h3>
  </div>
 </div>



 <div id="rightPanel">
  <h2>Photography</h2>


   <div class="pic1">

   <a href="images/pic2_large.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Beautiful Winter"> 
    <img src="images/pic2.jpg"> 
    </a> 
   </div> 

    <div class="pic2">

   <a href="images/pic3_large.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="Cottage"> 
    <img src="images/pic3.jpg"> 
    </a> 
   </div> 

   <div class="pic3">
  <a href="images/pic4_large.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="9-11"> 
    <img src="images/pic4.jpg"> 
    </a> 
   </div> 


  <div class="contacts">
   <h2>Quick Note</h2>

<form class="contact_form" method="post" action="process.php"  name="contact_form">



   <p>Name</p>
   <input name="name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />


     <p>Email</p>
   <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" />


     <p>Note</p>
     <input name="comments" id="comm" placeholder="Your Message" />



   <div class="blank2"></div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
   </form>

  </div>



  <div class="project">
   <h2>Project Links</h2>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">My Personal Website</a></li>
    <li><a href="Ulen Civic and Commerce Webste By Jenifer Troska/main.html">Ulen Civic &amp; Commerce</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">My Professional Website (coming soon)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footPanel">
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><div class="blank">|</div></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><div class="blank">|</div></li>
    <li><a href="family.html">Family</a></li>
    <li><div class="blank">|</div></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><div class="blank">|</div></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">© Jenifer Troska &#8226; 2014 &#8226; All Rights Reserved.                 
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Jenifertroska"><img src="images/social media/1391307458_facebook.png" alt="facebook" width="40" height="40" class="social-media-icons" /></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/110481900379360519368/"><img src="images/social media/1391307464_google.png" alt="google plus" width="40" height="40" class="social-media-icons" /></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/jeniferLTroska"><img src="images/social media/1391307501_twitter.png" alt="twitter" width="40" height="40" class="social-media-icons" /></a><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/jenifertroska/"><img src="images/social media/1391307492_p.png" alt="pinterest" width="40" height="40" class="social-media-icons" /></a></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS ----

```
body{margin:0px; padding:0px; background:#fffde4 url(../images/bodyBg.jpg) repeat-x}


#mainWrap{width:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; background:url(../images/headBg.jpg) no-repeat}
#leftPanel .about .emailaddress a { font-size:16px; margin-left:180px; color:#bb9d59; text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#leftPanel .about .emailaddress a:hover {font-weight:bold; color:#943415;}

#mainPanel{
    width: 990px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
}
#logoWrap{width:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left}


h1{width:223px; height:48px; margin:70px 0 0 0; padding:0 110px; float:right; line-height:10px; text-indent:-9999px; background:url(../images/jenlogo.png) no-repeat}

#webdesign {
            width: 223px;
            height: 38px;
            margin: 90px 0 0 0;
            padding: 0 110px;
            float: right;
            line-height: 7px;
            text-indent: 0;
            color: #26606D;
            font-style: italic;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
#quots{width:990px; margin:145px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}
#quots p{margin:0px; font-family:Georgia; font-size:28px; color:#497f35; line-height:32px; text-align:center; text-indent:50px}
#leftPanel{width:637px; margin:27px 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 35px; float:left}
#leftPanel .about{width:604px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left}
#leftPanel .about h2{
    width: 604px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0b636b;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
#leftPanel .about h3{width:604px; margin:4px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Georgia; font-size:18px; color:#943415; line-height:32px; font-weight:normal}
#leftPanel .about p{
    width: 590px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #bb9d59;
    line-height: 16px;
    background-color: #FFFDE4;
}
#leftPanel .about p span{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
#leftPanel .about .date{width:600px; height:29px; margin:30px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; background:#f9f6d4}
#leftPanel .about .date .left{width:139px; height:29px; margin:0px; padding:0 0 0 35px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#bb9d59; line-height:30px; font-weight:bold; background:url(../images/cal.jpg) no-repeat 11px 0}
#leftPanel .about .date .right{width:65px; height:29px; margin:0px; padding:0 0 0 38px; float:left; background:url(../images/read.jpg) no-repeat 12px 0}
#leftPanel .about .date .right a{font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#943415; line-height:30px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none}
#leftPanel .services{width:604px; margin:34px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}
#leftPanel .services h2{width:604px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Georgia; font-size:24px; color:#2c787b; line-height:28px; font-weight:normal}
#leftPanel .services .pic{width:163px; height:202px; margin:15px 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 28px; float:left; background:url(../images/homepagejenface.jpg) no-repeat}

#leftPanel .services .pic a{font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; color:#943415; line-height:14px; margin:146px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; width:123px}

#leftPanel .services p{
    width: 390px;
    margin: 14px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #bb9d59;
    line-height: 16px;
}
#leftPanel .services p span{font-weight:bold}


#leftPanel .services h3{width:390px; margin:13px 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 20px; float:left; font-family:Georgia; font-size:18px; color:#5c4527; line-height:22px; font-weight:normal}
#leftPanel .services ul{width:390px; margin:5px 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 20px; float:left; display:block}
#leftPanel .services ul li{width:390px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; display:block}

#leftPanel .services ul li a{width:372px; height:22px; margin:0px; padding:0 0 0 18px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#943415; line-height:20px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:#d8cd2f dashed 1px; background:url(../images/listStyle.jpg) no-repeat 2px 6px}

#leftPanel .services ul li a.bottom{width:372px; height:22px; margin:0px; padding:0 0 0 18px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#943415; line-height:20px; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:0px; background:url(../images/listStyle.jpg) no-repeat 2px 6px}

#leftPanel .services ul li a:hover {font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;}


#leftPanel .testimonial{width:590px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left}
#leftPanel .testimonial h2{width:590px; margin:30px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Georgia; font-size:24px; color:#2c787b; line-height:28px; font-weight:normal}
#leftPanel .testimonial p{width:590px; margin:13px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#bb9d59; line-height:16px; text-indent:12px; background:url(../images/quo.jpg) no-repeat}
#leftPanel .testimonial p span{font-weight:bold}
/*#leftPanel .testimonial p .dqo{width:11px; height:9px; text-indent:-9999px; background:url(images/quo.jpg) no-repeat}*/
#leftPanel .testimonial h3{width:100px; height:17px; margin:6px 0 0 0; padding:0 0 12px 28px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#943415; font-weight:bold; background:url(../images/testimIco.jpg) no-repeat}
#leftPanel .testimonial h3 span{font-weight:normal}

#leftPanel .services .projects2 {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: 220px;
}



#rightPanel{width:266px; margin:40px 0 0 0; padding:0 0 74px 36px; float:left; background:url(../images/rigthBg.jpg) no-repeat}
#rightPanel  h2{width:262px;  margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Georgia; font-size:24px; color:#0b636b; line-height:28px; font-weight:normal}

#rightPanel .view{width:58px; margin:3px 2px 0 0; padding:0 0 0 15px; float:right; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#943415; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; background:url(../images/listStyle.jpg) no-repeat 0 4px}

#rightPanel .pic1{width:262px; height:68px; margin:15px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; background:url(../images/pic2.jpg) no-repeat}
#rightPanel .pic2{width:262px; height:68px; margin:13px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; background:url(../images/pic3.jpg) no-repeat}
#rightPanel .pic3{width:262px; height:68px; margin:13px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; background:url(../images/pic4.jpg) no-repeat}


#rightPanel .contacts{width:266px; margin:18px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}
#rightPanel .contacts h2{padding:0 0 2px 0}
#rightPanel .contacts p{
    width: 42px;
    height: 19px;
    margin: 12px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #bb9d59;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-align: left;
}
#rightPanel .contacts input{width:207px; height:16px; margin:12px 0 0 0; padding:2px 0 0 9px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; color:#000000; border:#e8e6c8 solid 1px; background:#f8f5d2}
#rightPanel .contacts a{width:93px; height:19px; margin:12px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#943415; line-height:18px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; background:url(../images/contactsBg.jpg) no-repeat}
#rightPanel .contacts .blank{width:10px; height:19px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left}
#rightPanel .contacts .blank2{width:42px; height:19px; margin:12px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}


#rightPanel .project{width:266px; margin:30px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}
#rightPanel .project ul{width:260px; margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; display:block}
#rightPanel .project ul li{width:260px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; display:block}

#rightPanel .project ul li a{width:250px; height:21px; margin:0px; padding:0 0 0 10px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#bb9d59; line-height:18px; text-decoration:none; background:url(../images/listbg.jpg) no-repeat}
#rightPanel .project ul li a:hover{font-weight:bold; color:#943415}
#rightPanel .project ul li a.bottom{width:250px; height:20px; margin:0px; padding:0 0 0 10px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#bb9d59; line-height:18px; text-decoration:none; background:url(../images/listbg.jpg) no-repeat}
#rightPanel .project ul li a.bottom:hover{font-weight:bold; color:#943415} 

#rightPanel .activities {width:266px; margin:30px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}
#rightPanel .activities ul {width:260px; margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; display:block}
#rightPanel .activities ul li {
    width: 250px;
    height: 21px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #bb9d59;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url(../images/listbg.jpg) no-repeat; list-style-type:none;
}

#footPanel{width:923px; margin:0px; padding:25px 0 29px 0; float:left; background:url(../images/footbg.jpg) no-repeat center top}
#footPanel .nav{width:923px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left}
#footPanel .nav ul{width:375px; margin:0 auto; padding:0px; display:block}
#footPanel .nav ul li{width:auto; margin:0px; float:left; padding:0px; display:block}
#footPanel .nav ul li .blank{width:auto; margin:0px; padding:0 7px 0 7px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:#943415}
#footPanel .nav ul li a{width:auto; margin:0px; float:left; padding:0px; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:#943415; text-decoration:none}
#footPanel .copyright{
    width: 923px;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #bb9d59;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: static;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 88px;
}
#footPanel .designInfo{width:923px; margin:3px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; color:#bb9d59; text-align:center}
#footPanel .designInfo a{color:#943415; text-decoration:none}
#footPanel .validation{width:923px; margin:4px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}
#footPanel .validation ul{width:138px; margin:0 auto; padding:0px; display:block}
#footPanel .validation ul li{width:auto; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; display:block}
#footPanel .validation ul li .blank{width:6px; height:17px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left}
#footPanel .validation ul li a{width:66px; height:17px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; color:#943415; line-height:16px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; background:url(../images/validationBg.jpg) no-repeat}
#menu{width:990px; margin:32px 0 0 0; padding:0px; float:left}
#menu ul{width:450px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:right; display:block}
#menu ul li{width:auto; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; display:block}
#menu ul li a{width:auto; height:18px; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#45ada9; line-height:13px; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer}
#menu ul li a:hover{background:url(../images/rightCurve.jpg) no-repeat right}
#menu ul li a span{width:auto; height:16px; margin:0px; padding:2px 8px 0 8px; float:left; cursor:pointer}
#menu ul li a:hover span{background:url(../images/leftCurve.jpg) no-repeat left}
#menu ul li .blank{width:1px; height:18px; margin:0px; padding:0 5px 0 5px; float:left; background:url(../images/mBlank.jpg) no-repeat center top}
.social-media-icons {
    float: right;
}
#goals {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #bb9d59;
    background-color: #fffde4;
    padding: 0px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 250px;
}
/*Media CSS */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
#mainWrap:{ width:50%;}
#mainPael: {width:50%;} 
h1 {width:50%;
}
#webdesign {width:50%;}
#logoWrap {width:50%;}
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related, somewhat not: you don't really need to get as specific as you have with a LOT of that CSS. Since you have outright specified a lot of those widths, you WILL run into issues as your media queries would have to be extremely specific as well. I'd look to simplifying some of those CSS rules.

Comment: Patrick- I understand what you are saying. My widths are so specifically set on EVERYTHING in my CSS. I have attempted to adjust this with percentages - not a good idea. Can you please take a minute to tell me how you would recommend I simplify my CSS rules? Appreciate the help.

Comment: I'd really look into using some sort of grid-based CSS system - like Bootstrap or something "lighter". You will get much more predictable results by using a grid that TONS of people have used and have worked all the kinks out of.

Answer (score 0):

you can use media query to load deferent css file style, or using media query in same file,

```
if you would like use media query in one file you can using this 

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}


@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

we used min-width alone, when we needed to execute code when screen is more than number 
such as: min-width: 1224px; thats mean execute when screen width is equal or more than 1224px

and max-width is Reverse min-width, also using both when needed a range width screen

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html
```